# SQL Database error generated during IIS deployment

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, iis

my `asp.net` application runs successfully in development server of visual studio. but when i deploy my application in `IIS` it generates the error as follows

> Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in
>   retrieving the user's local application data path. Please make sure
>   the user has a local user profile on the computer. The connection will
>   be closed.

what are the necessary changes that i should do in my application. also guide me how to deploy my database on `IIS`.

Answer (score 0):

What is your connection string?
More specifically, I am wondering if you are using a .mdf file as your database.

If this is the case, you need to ensure that your web application has write-permissions within the App_Data folder of your website.

Comment: can u guide me how to deploy my asp.net application project along with ASPNETDB.MDF present in app_Data folder and my project database .i am using sql server express.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say exactly without seeing your connection string, but possibly this KB article will help.  It relates to SQLExpress and the error you are seeing.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2002980